# Firebase reference doesn't get anything

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem**

I am trying to retrieve data off of my firevase server, and the reference code I am using to do so doesn't retrieve anything.

```
getItems(){
```

var items = [];

var query = firebase.database().ref('users').child(expoID).orderByKey();

query.once('value', (snap) => {

var items = [];

snap.forEach( (child) => {

items.push({

content: child.val().content,

postKey: child.val().okey,

color: child.val().color,

notifKey: child.key

});

});

items.reverse();

}).then(() => {

this.setState({firebaseItems: items});

});

```
}
```

expoID is a predefined variable, defined with expo's constants.

### **Server**

[image: firebase server] 
The first items under users is the expoID seen in the code above. I tested, and its the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

orderByKey only creates a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderByKey).
To retrieve the actual data you need to listen for an event. [once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#once) and [on](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on) are your friends here. There are following event types: "value", "child_added", "child_changed", "child_removed" and "child_moved."

To get the data use "value". So the code to get your data once for example is:

```
ref('users').child(expoID).orderByKey().once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

```
// Notice I removed the first declaration of var items
// var items = [];

var query = firebase.database().ref('users').child(expoID).orderByKey();

query.once('value', (snap) => {

  // This array is ONLY valid inside this callback
  var items = [];

  snap.forEach((child) => {
    items.push({
      content: child.val().content,
      postKey: child.val().okey,
      color: child.val().color,
      notifKey: child.key
    });
  });
  items.reverse();
  this.setState({ firebaseItems: items });
});
// No need to set your state in the promise. Just do it directly inside the callback
```

Comment: I updated my answer to show the whole code. I think the query is actually what I want in that code. Sorry the code isnt formatted as code, I&#39;m on my phone and it won&#39;t work.

Comment: You declared items 2 times. The two **ARE NOT** the same. So you pushed your items on the inside one but called setState outside (in .then), so firebaseItems is always empty no matter what. See my updated answer.